# Alternative of a query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a query :

```
 SELECT TOP 21
        *
 FROM   (
          SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY contacts.id ) AS row_number,
                  contacts.id,
                  contacts.first_name,
                  accounts.name account_name,
                  jtl0.account_id account_id,
                  contacts.lead_source,
                  contacts.date_entered,
                  LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(jt1.first_name, '') + N'
' + ISNULL(jt1.last_name, ''))) assigned_user_name,
                  jt1.created_by assigned_user_name_owner,
                  N'Users' assigned_user_name_mod,
                  contacts.assigned_user_id
          FROM    contacts
          LEFT JOIN accounts_contacts jtl0
                  ON contacts.id = jtl0.contact_id
                     AND jtl0.deleted = 0
          LEFT JOIN accounts accounts
                  ON accounts.id = jtl0.account_id
                     AND accounts.deleted = 0
                     AND accounts.deleted = 0
          LEFT JOIN users jt1
                  ON contacts.assigned_user_id = jt1.id
                     AND jt1.deleted = 0
                     AND jt1.deleted = 0
          WHERE   contacts.deleted = 0
        ) AS a
 WHERE  a.row_number > 319080
```

The above query has worst performance but if I remove "top 21" from query it perform very well and it also perform with "top 21" well if I remove "WHERE a.row_number > 319080"  from query.

1.

```
SELECT TOP 21
        *
FROM    (
          SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY contacts.id ) AS row_number,
                  contacts.id,
                  contacts.first_name,
                  accounts.name account_name,
                  jtl0.account_id account_id,
                  contacts.lead_source,
                  contacts.date_entered,
                  LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(jt1.first_name, '') + N'
' + ISNULL(jt1.last_name, ''))) assigned_user_name,
                  jt1.created_by assigned_user_name_owner,
                  N'Users' assigned_user_name_mod,
                  contacts.assigned_user_id
          FROM    contacts
          LEFT JOIN accounts_contacts jtl0
                  ON contacts.id = jtl0.contact_id
                     AND jtl0.deleted = 0
          LEFT JOIN accounts accounts
                  ON accounts.id = jtl0.account_id
                     AND accounts.deleted = 0
                     AND accounts.deleted = 0
          LEFT JOIN users jt1
                  ON contacts.assigned_user_id = jt1.id
                     AND jt1.deleted = 0
                     AND jt1.deleted = 0
          WHERE   contacts.deleted = 0
        ) AS a
```

2.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
          SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY contacts.id ) AS row_number,
                  contacts.id,
                  contacts.first_name,
                  accounts.name account_name,
                  jtl0.account_id account_id,
                  contacts.lead_source,
                  contacts.date_entered,
                  LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(jt1.first_name, '') + N'
' + ISNULL(jt1.last_name, ''))) assigned_user_name,
                  jt1.created_by assigned_user_name_owner,
                  N'Users' assigned_user_name_mod,
                  contacts.assigned_user_id
          FROM    contacts
          LEFT JOIN accounts_contacts jtl0
                  ON contacts.id = jtl0.contact_id
                     AND jtl0.deleted = 0
          LEFT JOIN accounts accounts
                  ON accounts.id = jtl0.account_id
                     AND accounts.deleted = 0
                     AND accounts.deleted = 0
          LEFT JOIN users jt1
                  ON contacts.assigned_user_id = jt1.id
                     AND jt1.deleted = 0
                     AND jt1.deleted = 0
          WHERE   contacts.deleted = 0
        ) AS a
WHERE   a.row_number > 319080
```

Comment: I assume that there is a (clustered) primary key on `contacts (id)` but is there an index on `contacts (deleted)` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give much specific advice when we lack schema, sample data etc.

However, generally speaking if your TOP is slow, it's because you select data in an order which is hurting your query, causing the engine to sort/order the data in a direction which isn't similar to how your indexes are built.

If ROW_NUMBER() or any window function is slow, it's because you select from a large data set and/or like above sort the data inefficient. (It's a "window" function after all, meaning it runs after the query).

So my advice would be to start splitting the query into smaller segments and make sure your indexes are correct and that you have no SORT operation in the execution plans.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow Allan's suggestion.
But just for fun, can you run the query as:

```
SELECT TOP 21 * 
   FROM (
      SELECT  *
         FROM    (
                SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY contacts.id ) AS row_number,
                        ...
              ) AS a
    WHERE   a.row_number > 319080) AS b
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying an `ORDER BY` for the `TOP(21)`. That can cause random rows to be returned. The behavior of `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is not deterministic.

You have however already a `ROW_NUMBER` that you could also use to restrict the rows. As this query is running fast

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
          SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY contacts.id ) AS row_number,
                  contacts.id,
                  contacts.first_name,
                  accounts.name account_name,
                  jtl0.account_id account_id,
                  contacts.lead_source,
                  contacts.date_entered,
                  LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(jt1.first_name, '') + N'
' + ISNULL(jt1.last_name, ''))) assigned_user_name,
                  jt1.created_by assigned_user_name_owner,
                  N'Users' assigned_user_name_mod,
                  contacts.assigned_user_id
          FROM    contacts
          LEFT JOIN accounts_contacts jtl0
                  ON contacts.id = jtl0.contact_id
                     AND jtl0.deleted = 0
          LEFT JOIN accounts accounts
                  ON accounts.id = jtl0.account_id
                     AND accounts.deleted = 0
                     AND accounts.deleted = 0
          LEFT JOIN users jt1
                  ON contacts.assigned_user_id = jt1.id
                     AND jt1.deleted = 0
                     AND jt1.deleted = 0
          WHERE   contacts.deleted = 0
        ) AS a
WHERE   a.row_number > 319080
```

this one will most likely too:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
          SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY contacts.id ) AS row_number,
                  contacts.id,
                  contacts.first_name,
                  accounts.name account_name,
                  jtl0.account_id account_id,
                  contacts.lead_source,
                  contacts.date_entered,
                  LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(jt1.first_name, '') + N'
' + ISNULL(jt1.last_name, ''))) assigned_user_name,
                  jt1.created_by assigned_user_name_owner,
                  N'Users' assigned_user_name_mod,
                  contacts.assigned_user_id
          FROM    contacts
          LEFT JOIN accounts_contacts jtl0
                  ON contacts.id = jtl0.contact_id
                     AND jtl0.deleted = 0
          LEFT JOIN accounts accounts
                  ON accounts.id = jtl0.account_id
                     AND accounts.deleted = 0
                     AND accounts.deleted = 0
          LEFT JOIN users jt1
                  ON contacts.assigned_user_id = jt1.id
                     AND jt1.deleted = 0
                     AND jt1.deleted = 0
          WHERE   contacts.deleted = 0
        ) AS a
WHERE   a.row_number > 319080 
  AND   a.row_number < 319102
```

It also returns only 21 rows but does not require an additional execution plan operator that the `TOP` does, so it should use the same execution plan as the fast but not restricted version above does.

Comment: The above query works fine if I exclude  " AND   a.row_number < 319102" part and if I include this the query returns the same execution plan as for the TOP and goes into nested loops.

Comment: Have you updated your statistics lately?

Comment: My problem has been resolved. Actually there was mismatch of datatypes of join column, one is varchar and second one is nvarchar. As I make both column of same datatype query returns result in quick. Thanks!